# Set focus on next TextInput when user used Autofill

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

Is there a way in React Native to shift focus if the user used Autofill for a TextInput?

For example I have two TextInputs, one for firstname and one for lastname. If the user press "John" from the autofill suggestion, I would like the focus to shift to the other input for the lastname to prevent having to click "Next" or actively click on the next input.

Example code:

```
<TextInput
    ref={firstNameRef}
    textContentType='givenName'
    returnKeyType='next'
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    onSubmitEditing={() => lastNameRef.current?.focus()}
/>

<TextInput
    ref={lastNameRef}
    textContentType='familyName'
/>
```

So I know my `onSubmitEditing()` handles the shift of focus when the user press "Return/Next", and I was hoping Autofill would trigger this as well, but it doesn't of course. I also tried it with `onEndEditing={() => lastNameRef.current?.focus()}` but it doesn't get triggered by Autofill either.

Is what I'm trying to do possible in React Native, and is it only iOS specific? Because I know the 'textContentType' is for iOS, but I would love for a solution for Android as well if there is one.

***[EDIT]***

Found kind of a hot fix that will have to do for now:

```
const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState<string>('')

onChangeText={(value: string) => {
    value.length - firstname.length > 1
    ? (lastnameInput.current?.focus(),
      setFirstname(value))
    : setFirstname(value)
}}
```

Checking the length of the input against the length of firstname, the code decides that if the input value was increased with more than one letter the user used Autofill (or Word Suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

Can we do like this, using a state which stores a boolean value if true then set the focus of next input. So when entering the first name if user click on a suggestion set that state boolean state to true and use that state to focus the last name.

Comment: Yeah sure, but how do we achieve that, when is the boolean meant to be set to true? I feel like there might be some sort of event that we could tap into maybe? I'm just not sure if react native has access to it. I mean yeah, I guess I could write something that checks the length of previous input value with the length of current input value and if the difference is like 2 or more the user probably used Autofill. How ever I am not sure this is bullet proof and might get triggered by very fast typing or a slower device...